# phpmyadmin can't add more than 1000 columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever I try to add another column to any table that already has 1000 columns I get the following error in phpmyadmin:

> MySQL said:
>
> ## 1005 - Can't create table 'dealbuilder_NEW.#sql-2996_261' (errno: 139) Please check privileges of directory containing database.

I've tried absolutely everything including changing users/permissions/groups on server and in phpmydamin as well as changing 'Maximum displayed SQL length' from 1000 to 5000. Please help!

The table doesn't contain any rows and is only 64kb

Running on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: If you're creating 1000 columns per row you're alomost certainly doing something wrong. There are a number of limits that might affect what you're doing - see [this reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html) for more information.

Comment: Why do your table contain >1000 columns? Do you mean 1000 rows instead?

Comment: Please refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html . Hope this will help you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this table? Perhaps we can help you find a way to improve the data structure to avoid this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can have at most of 4096 columns per table. But, The exact limit depends on many interacting factors(Get details on below mentioned link).

Every table has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. Suppose one cell of your table requires 765 bytes then calculation will be as :

```
 Number of Columns in Table = 65,535/765
 Number of Columns in Table = 85
```

For more details please refer the below mentioned link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html